# CSS way of looping a background image with cover or contain sizing

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations

Say you are trying to animate a tilable background like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 91px;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat-x left center;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes displace {
  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }
}
@keyframes displace {
  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg"></textarea>
</div>
```

As soon as you change the dimensions of the container, the looping animation breaks!

**Is there any way to make this responsive without JS?**

Comment: I dont see the animation break at all whats happening at your end?

Comment: @DCdaz reescale the textarea, it will start jumping at the end of the loop

Comment: @DCdaz change the dimensions of the textarea

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that, to make it responsive, you need to set the animated background-position using percentages.

But, when you set background-size as cover or contain, in some cases the width is adjusted to 100%. In this case, background-position using percentages is useless (won't move it).

The only way that I have found to manage this is moving the image to a pseudo element, and moving it. To keep the continuity, though, we will need two pseudo elements.

But that won't work on a textarea.

You didn't said anything about textarea being a requirement, so I am posting this. To show that it works on resize, hover it.

```css
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
   width: 220px;  
}
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg:before, .bg:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBHey.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    animation: move 2s infinite linear;
}

.bg:before {
    right: 100%;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {transform: translateX(  0%);}
      to {transform: translateX(100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

[image: test image]

Comment: I think that now it works ok. Changed size from contain to 100%

Comment: I have changed the image so that it is easier to check. Looks fine to me, at least in Chrome. Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: This solution is very nice, but now that I see it... this is about animating background-position, not about translate...

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari (but should if you add `-webkit` versions of `animate` and `keyframes`)

Comment: @tavnab OP didn't mention a need for Safari support.

Comment: @TylerH, that's true; I meant it as a caveat (with a fix) for future readers wanting to solve a similar problem but with cross-browser support. There could be many Safari users who'd see this answer, run the code snippet, see no animation, and down-vote thinking the answer as a whole is flawed rather than just missing the CSS for `-webkit`.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to make it work by making the background twice as big.

I know this isn't the perfect solution, but maybe you can do a trick with the image size or something to make it look the way you wanted it to.

```css
    .container {width: 160px;height: 91px;}
    .bg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat-x left center;
      background-size: 200%;
      -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
      animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes displace {
      from { background-position: left center;
      } to { background-position: 200% center; }
    }
    @keyframes displace {
      from { background-position: left center;
      } to { background-position: 200% center; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"><textarea class="bg"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: this could be good but the question mentions cover/contain, with your solution you loose a lot of the image. If abstract, like in this case, it is not important, but with patterns or other things, it does matter!

Comment: Yes I know it's not an ideal solution. I know this is a pretty ridiculous solution, but you could try merging 4 images into one, which would cancel out the enlargement.

Comment: but if we could understand why this happens maybe it could be posible to find a better one! it must have some logic to it...

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is with the `height` resizing and your different settings. To get it to work with your actual settings, the displace would have to be 2x the `height` of the image (since the image has a ration of 2:1). I don't think you can do only by `css`.

But you have different options. I'm not sure exactly which part of you display you want to keep, so here are three ways to get your translation working on `resize`. None have exactly your settings, because the ones you have make it hard (impossible?) to set the proper displacement. Since you're stretching the width depending on the height, it's hard to follow. Via JS it would be easy, but css has limited access to these values.

The solutions proposed keep the height constant so you can keep your displace value constant.

First one, the background-size is the size of the container in px.

Second solution, you resize textarea only on x axis.

Third you repeat on y axis and keep height and width fixed.

There are probably other workarounds that are maybe more suited to your specific needs.

```css
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
   margin: 10px;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat-x left center;
  background-size: 160px 80px;
     padding: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
}
.bg2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat-x left center;
  background-size: contain;
     padding: 0px;
    resize: horizontal;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
}
.bg3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat left center;
  background-size: 160px 80px;
     padding: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes displace {
  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }
}
@-keyframes displace {
  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg2"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Ilpo's answer, except it doesn't resize the image (`background-size: auto;`). The animation is smooth throughout, regardless of container size.

The downside is that the width (200px) of the image needs to be known beforehand.

Since you said tilable, and since this image looks to be tilable in both directions, I also made it repeat in both dimensions. As a result, your `textarea` is filled with the tiled background image, animated to scroll horizontally. If you only want to tile in 1 direction, you can change `repeat` back to `repeat-x` and change the vertical position from `top` to whatever you need.

```css
.container {width: 160px;height: 91px;}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat left top;
  background-size: auto;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes displace {
  from { background-position: 0px top; }
  to   { background-position: 200px top; }
}

@keyframes displace {
  from { background-position: 0px top; }
  to   { background-position: 200px top; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><textarea class="bg"></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> For each `background-position: 200px bottom;` you need to add `1second` for example if you want add 2S, you add another 200px so you
>   make it `background-position: 400px bottom;` I think.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 91px;
}

.bg {
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) fixed;
  -webkit-animation: displace 1s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes displace {
  from { background-position: 0 bottom; }
  to { background-position: 200px bottom; }
}

@keyframes displace {
  from { background-position: 0 bottom; }
  to { background-position: 200px bottom;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg"></textarea>
</div>
```

**I hope it works for your case, Let me know if you have any question.**

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://i60.tinypic.com/2j2fhjm.jpg) repeat-x left center;
  -webkit-animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  animation: displace 2s linear infinite;
  background-size: 160px 100%;
}

.bg {
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 91px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes displace {

  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }

  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }

}

@keyframes displace {

  from {
    background-position: 0 center;
  }

  to {
    background-position: 160px center;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="bg"></textarea>
</div>
```